# picklist from database newbie

Tags: database, list, salesforce

Total newbie to salesforce, I need some direction on how to create a lookup box. Which I did, but the values are pulled from salesforce database that I would populate.

Table will have this format, Name,balance,amount,paid. When I select test1name it populates some other fields with balance,amount,paid so I can do calculations with those amounts.

Thanks.help me

```
 Table
   Name|Balance|Amount|Paid
   test1name|500|20|200
   test2name|1000|10|300
```

Comment: You mean you have a table of information as above, and when you click the name you want to copy the values from the other cells to other input fields on the page? Or you want to do some calculations in apex for the chosen record and then return the results to the page?

Answer (score 0):

Where is picklist question? Do you want to use it somewhere or what?

While you will (or will not) answer my questions I post some tips for you. Hope they will help you somehow.

For example you have you sObject with all thous fields.
In Visualforce page I would do next things.

```
 <apex:pageBlockSection id="myContentSection" title="My Content Section" columns="1">
  <apex:inputField value="{!myObject.Id}" >
   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="pullObjectById" reRender="myContentSection" />
  </apex:inputField>
  <apex:inputField value="{!myObject.Name}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!myObject.Balance}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!myObject.Amount}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!myObject.Paid}"/>
 </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

In controller class there will be a method

```
public myObjectType myObject {get;set;}

public PageReference pullObjectById() {
 myObject = [ select Id, Name, Balance, Amount, Paid from myObjectTable where Id =:myObject.Id];
 return null;
}
```

So when you select an object from lookup window you will have all other fields populated on your page.